# How to Authenticate Amazon S3 Restful Calls Without SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I want to make Restful S3 calls to upload/download/list files in my buckets. The AWS website explains everything in detail but it's a bit complicated and time consuming to write from scratch. Can anyone please share some sample code they might have?

(I know this breaks stackoverflow rules but I'm going to answer my own question anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to download a file from S3 by generating a temporary AuthKey using AccessKey/SecretKey combo. I use this method to generate a temporary download link for our clients so they can download their files without requiring any kind of special access.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string accessKey = "ACCESS_KEY";
    string secretKey = "SECRET_KEY";
    string bucketName = "BUCKET_NAME";
    string pathToFile = "FOLDER1/FOLDER2/MyFile.txt";
    DateTime authKeyExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

    string authenticatedDownloadLink = GenerateDownloadLink(bucketName, pathToFile, authKeyExpirationDate, accessKey, secretKey);
    Console.WriteLine(authenticatedDownloadLink);
    Console.Read();
}

private static string GenerateDownloadLink(string bucketName, string pathToFile, DateTime expirationDate, string accessKey, string secretKey)
{
    Uri downloadLink = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/{1}", bucketName, pathToFile));

    string canonicalizedResource = string.Concat("/", bucketName, "/", pathToFile);

    int secondsSinceEpoch = GetSecondsSinceEpoch(expirationDate);
    string signature = GenerateStringToSign("GET", null, null, secondsSinceEpoch, null, canonicalizedResource);
    string str = SignSignature(signature, accessKey, secretKey);

    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nameValueCollection
        = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "AWSAccessKeyId", accessKey },
        { "Signature", str },
        { "Expires", secondsSinceEpoch.ToString() }
    };

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int num = 0;
    foreach (string key in nameValueCollection.Keys)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(key);
        stringBuilder.Append("=");
        stringBuilder.Append(nameValueCollection[key]);
        num++;
        if (num == nameValueCollection.Keys.Count)
        {
            continue;
        }
        stringBuilder.Append("&");
    }

    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(downloadLink)
    {
        Query = stringBuilder.ToString()
    };

    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}

private static int GetSecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime expirationDate)
{
    TimeSpan universalTime = expirationDate.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    return (int)universalTime.TotalSeconds;
}

private static string GenerateStringToSign(string httpVerb, string contentMD5, string contentType, int expires, string canonicalizedAmzHeaders, string canonicalizedResource)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(httpVerb);
    stringBuilder.Append("\n");
    stringBuilder.Append(contentMD5);
    stringBuilder.Append("\n");
    stringBuilder.Append(contentType);
    stringBuilder.Append("\n");
    stringBuilder.Append(expires);
    stringBuilder.Append("\n");
    stringBuilder.Append(canonicalizedAmzHeaders);
    stringBuilder.Append(canonicalizedResource);
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

private static string SignSignature(string signatureToSign, string accessKey, string secretKey)
{
    byte[] numArray = HMACSHA1_UTF8_Hash(signatureToSign, secretKey);
    return Uri.EscapeDataString(Base64Encode(numArray));
}

private static byte[] HMACSHA1_UTF8_Hash(string input, string key)
{
    byte[] numArray;
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 hMACSHA1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)))
    {
        numArray = hMACSHA1.ComputeHash(memoryStream);
    }
    return numArray;
}

private static string Base64Encode(byte[] data)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```